# Automatically add external display to screen in Ubuntu Server

Tags: 12.04, server, multiple-monitors, ssh, screen

I'd like to be able to control my laptop's (Ubuntu Server 12.04) external display over SSH. I know about the `screen` command, but it requires that I add the display from the laptop. Is there a way to automatically run `screen -S extmonitor` on startup, 'mounting' the screen?

Comment: When you talk about "display" you mean a GUI (aka xorg) or the screen (byobu) command?

Comment: @Braiam More the `screen` command. I can make my own GUI. I really only want to be able to display text.

Comment: Ok, then you want that screen which is displayed on the external monitor you can control it using SSH?

Comment: @Braiam Exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you dettached yourself of a screen session, you can recover it easily:

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    2112.pts-2.bt   (04/03/14 19:29:39) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-braiam.
```

Note here the `2112.pts-2.bt` that is the screen socket name. Now we use `-r` and `-S`:

```
screen -r -S 2112.pts-2.bt
```

`-r` means reattach, while `-S` indicates which socket name we are attaching to. To detach yourself again type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>.